# PHP JSON response - iterate through multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am running a rest api call that returns a JSON response, which I'd like to process in PHP.  The response is a bunch of arrays in the following format:

```
   [
  {
    "id": "auc48x87ts3oE9l6F0h7",
    "label": "Facebook",
    "linkUrl": "https://someurl.com",
    "logoUrl": "https://someurl.com/facebook.png",
    "appName": "facebook",
  },
  {
    "id": "auc4bd9we0llNsFtz0h7",
    "label": "Bank of America CashPro",
    "linkUrl": "https://someurl.com",
    "logoUrl": "https://someurl.com/bankofamericacashpro.png",
    "appName": "bankofamericacashpro",

  }]
```

I'd like to iterate through the whole response go I can get a nice list of appName values.

In my code I can't retrieve the app name at all of the first app, nevermind any others -

```
$output = curl_exec($curl);

  // have to get rid of leading trash on return for json_decode to work
    $output = "[" . strstr( $output, "{" ) . "]";

    //decode
    $jsonObject = json_decode($output, true);

    //get app name
    $appname =  $jsonObject['appName'];
```

My questions are, any ideas why the $appName variable doesnt store any value?  And once that is fixed, how do I create a loop that goes trhough each array in the response?  Is a foreach loop suitable here?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This seems to be a really basic problem: you are not iterating over your arrays. What did you try so far so solve this? Did you google 'iterating over an array in php'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `// have to get rid of leading trash on return for json_decode to work
>       $output = "[" . strstr( $output, "{" ) . "]";`

No, you don't! You recieve an array of objects that's what `[]` are for(example: `[1,2,{"id"=42},4]`), so you should parse it as array as says first annswer

Answer (score 1):

You will have to iterate

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($output, true);
foreach($jsonObject as $obj){

echo $obj['appName'];
}
```